# Sveltekit - Trigger function when new rows added to the Table element

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I'd like to trigger my toast function when a new rows added to the table with a sound notification.

```
    <script>
          function toastTrigger() {
            toast.push('Hello world!');
          }
        </script>
    
    <html>
//table code. with table tag etc.
    {#each Object.entries($catStore.rows) as [key, value], index (key)}
    
    <td on:change={toastTrigger}>{value.name}</td>
```

My idea is, when I write my new value.name in the table, it triggers the on:change event, but it does not.
Sound could be the same as above, but where should I call my on:change? Or any svelte specific solution? Thanks!

Comment: The problem here is that you think the TD HTML element has a change event.  It does not.  What you need to do is write an algorithm that detects additions to the list of entries ($catStore.rows) and emits a toast per added row.

Comment: so basically when catStore.rows number has changed, it triggers the toast function?

Comment: Basically, kind of, yes.  Svelte will tell you when store contents change.  Now all you need is to determine the reason for the change:  Addition of rows?  Deletion of rows?  Perhaps a property of the data changed?  That's the algorithm you need to develop.  Hint:  You'll most likely need a copy of the "previous" state in order to determine what changed.